# Handshake while holding own right elbow

Tags: culture, socializing

I have recently had contact with an acquaintance from Eastern Africa (I think from Ethiopia or Somalia). When the person greeted me, she shook my hand while holding her elbow of the right arm with the left hand (see image). After this happened a few times, I figured it was not just a coincidence.

Does this gesture have any meaning?

[image: drawing of person holding elbow]

Comment: I'm curious - do they put their hand over top their elbow or underneath? (your image doesn't show that, ha!)

Comment: Some of the answers, IMO, are lacking and just saying "It's just because..." - while I'm sure nowadays it's true, I'd think there's some origin of the gesture?  You could argue we shake hands, just because it's rude not to ...but the origin is generally to [show you're not holding a weapon](http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsround/37713970).  I wonder when the addition of touching your elbow was introduced in Africa, as it is apparently very commonplace.  (Maybe to show you're not hiding a weapon in that other hand?)

Comment: I feel like it's similar in (at least some parts of) Asia, where people would hold their wrist with their left hand while shaking your hand, maybe also how they would hand you their business cards with two hands. It's a form of respect.

Comment: Interesting --- in other cultures, holding your inner elbow is an [insulting gesture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bras_d%27honneur).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni It is not the "holding the inner elbow"; moving the forearm up is a part of the gesture. Without that part the movement means nothing.

Comment: @SJuan76 I ensure you that someone would find it offensive in Italy if you do something resembling it, like the example in this post.

Comment: Just to add to the existing answers the custom, at least between equals, is also to lean forward and to touch right shoulders. I cannot draw a diagram but putting "Ethiopian handshake shoulder" into your favourite search engine should give you plenty of images. I cannot now remember whether a woman ever greeted me (a man) this way nor do I remember seeing two women doing it but I am not that observant.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's a sign of respect. A bit like using both hands to shake yours. (Source: I lived in Africa for something like 7 years.)

I personally found this more common in West Africa than East Africa.

Edit: Perhaps as clarification, the right elbow typically is held with the left hand, as if to support the right arm. But, I've also often seen 'just' touching the right forearm with the fingers of the left hand.

Comment: I encountered this a lot in rural Malawi and not so much in rural Tanzania. My theory is that because Malawi receives few tourists, and fewer Americans, and especially fewer Americans with my skin tone, it was a bigger deal when I showed up in a village.

Comment: Come to think of it, this was also more common when I lived in Zimbabwe.

Comment: I can confirm that this is true for most cultures in Zimbabwe and South Africa as well. It is a sign of respect and I was taught it signified the weight of the other persons hand that you could not shake theirs with only your one.

Comment: Confirmed here in Uganda. You just do it because its rude not to

Answer (score 49):

As MastaBaba [said](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/108404), it's a sign of respect. As an Ethiopian, most of us were taught as children to hold our hand (anywhere on the forearm) when greeting elders (basically anyone older). It is considered rude to shake hands without holding one's arm, and in most cases the person (elder) will be offended. Sometimes, the person may also look down during the handshake, which is also another sign of respect.

Answer (score 15):

Having lived in Uganda Africa for almost 8 years I think I can answer your question.

Here in Uganda its a sign of respect. I often place my hand on my elbow when shaking the hands of the elderly because I acknowledge their old age and their knowledge. It means they acknowledge you and respect you. Like @Kidus answered its considered rude to not place your other hand on some part of your forearm. Sometimes the person will nod his/her head toward the ground while shaking your hand, Its also a sign of respect and it would be disrespectful not to follow suit.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is the respectful way of shaking hands. I assume this from reading The No 1 Ladies Detective Agency books (set in Botswana) where the main character refers to this as the proper way of shaking hands.  A foreigner who shows respect by shaking hands this way goes up in the character’s estimation.

Comment: With all due respect, an assumption based on a fiction book has little value compared to an answer from someone who lived in Africa.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev with all due respect, it is still an accepted source. We can assume the author did some research. Were we in Skeptics.SE maybe it would not be ok, but **bashing a newbie poster is not OK.** And Brontew, welcome to the Stack Exchange. I hope you stay around and build with us this awesome knowledge base.

Comment: @Mindwin _"bashing a newbie poster is not OK"_ <- Comments and votes on an answer are supposed to be based on their contents alone, not who happened to write it.

Comment: @Mindwin You seem to disagree with my comment. Would you seriously prefer traveling advice based on a fiction book to a first hand experience? And how exactly is my comment "bashing"? Can you suggest a polite version of it?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev what I prefer and upvote has nothing to do with the validity of posts. [*Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions. Don't expect new users to know all the rules — they don't. And be patient while they learn. If you're here for help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Everyone here is volunteering, and no one responds well to demands for help.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) - what I read from your comment above, is "Dear user, your answer is a piece of ****, learn 2 post". It is not constructive.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev for what it's worth, I would absolutely prefer traveling advice from a printed book, be it fiction or not, over the word of a random stranger on the internet, yes. No offense to any of the people who posted answers, but "I know because I lived there" is a completely unverifiable claim. So, if anything, "I know because I read it in a book" is better, not worse. Even if that book is a work of fiction. Of course it isn't a perfect source, it's just slightly better than "some random person on the internet told me".

Comment: @terdon If you want to compare apples to apples, this answer is "some random person on the internet told me what they have read in a book", unless of course you have read the book yourself, and made exactly the same assumptions as the poster.

Comment: @Mindwin Well, you're the easily insulted type if you read swear words I didn't even write.

Answer (score 5):

Just as another place where it is done, this is the standard way of shaking hands in the sport of Taekwondo. See [this page](http://www.sheridantaekwondo.com/etiquette.htm) for example:

> *Shaking Hands*
>
> A Taekwon-Do handshake is always given with two hands. With the right hand extended, place the left hand palm down under the right elbow. This is a gesture of respect and should be used at all times, even outside the dojang, when giving or receiving items, as well as when shaking hands.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This answer was flagged for quality, possibly because it doesn't address the actual question that was asked, about the gesture as used in East Africa. At least, you have not presented a case connecting the two, as it's extremely unlikely that formal practice in a Korean martial art is what informs the folk practice on the other side of the hemisphere. As such, it might have been better-received as a comment.

Comment: @choster Yeah, I suppose. The question title is **Handshake while holding own right elbow**  and the only actual question in the text is **Does this gesture have any meaning?** so I thought the relevance is direct, if not specifically for Africa.

Comment: This is exactly what came to mind for me when I saw the question title. Even pouring drinks is done in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

My experience is with Nepal, transaction like paying or gifting are conducted with the right hand.  Placing the left hand on the right elbow connotes greater respect or formality to the transaction.  Adding the hand to elbow is like changing "Its nice to meet you" to "Its **very** nice to meet you" or "Thank you" to "Thank you, sir".

Comment: I'm not sure of the connection between your two sentences here, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Edited